# Key event on Ext.grid.panel

Tags: extjs4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ExtJS 4 and its new MVC: grid: how to handle keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941037/extjs-4-and-its-new-mvc-grid-how-to-handle-keys)

I need to add key listener to Ext.grid.Panel (i.e. key listener for space, left, right). Actually I need to catch 'keyup' or some other key related event on Panel. I tried everything but without success. Anybody have some idea?  I'm using Extjs 4.

Answer (score 6):

If a component doesn't directly expose key events, you need to do a little bit of work. This may not be the best way to go about this, but it's a start.

The first trick is knowing that some DOM elements like `div` don't fire key events unless they have a tab index. So do something like this: `grid.getEl().set({tabindex: "0"})` to get things rolling.

Now your grid element will fire key events. Next step is to add a KeyMap that targets your grid. There's a couple ways you can do this, but here's a good one:

```
grid.getEl().addKeyMap({
    eventName: "keyup",
    binding: [{
        key: Ext.EventObject.SPACE,
        fn:  function(){ console.log("Space key pressed"); }
    },{
        key:   [Ext.EventObject.LEFT, Ext.EventObject.RIGHT],
        shift: true,
        fn:    function(){ console.log("Left or right pressed while pressing shift"); }
    }]
});
```

Basically, `binding` is an array of objects that specify one or more keys to listen for and a function to trigger. You can learn more about it if you check the [Ext.util.KeyMap](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap) documentation.

Notice the use of `eventName` above. You can set one type of event per KeyMap. So if you want to bind to both keydown and keyup events, you need two KeyMaps on the same element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpfull and solve my problem.

Comment: tabindex can be added in component properties like this: autoEl: { tabindex: 0 }. Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3pbq

Answer (score 0):

For starters, have a look at [KeyMap](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap).